# Access Tablet Internal Memory from Third-party application

Tags: android

[image]I am trying to built an application that will alllow user to paste a text file in the Tablet Internal memory by browsing it trough connecting with PC ( IN SPECIFIC DIRECTORY ) and do some file-operations to it through application. After that user will be able to  browse the directory again and copy the final-file .

IS there a way to do that?

I can store the final-file in application 'SANDBOX" through application but the user will not be able browse the sandbox. So what is the possible solutions

THANKS

Comment: The volume pictured above is the device's "external storage" (pseudo-)partition, even though it happens to not be removable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files created in an application's private storage (what you are calling the "sandbox") area can be given mode world readable so that other tools can access them, however relatively few other applications would know how to find them.

Files that you desire to make generally available should be placed instead on the "external storage" which confusingly on a lot of devices (especially tablets) is built in, rather than a removable memory card.  At this point what really distinguishes "external storage" is that data there is naturally shared between apps and easily browsed by the user with common file manager apps (android doesn't tend to come with a file manager, but there are lots out there you can add)

Comment: But is there a way an application can read file from internal memory of the tablet? I know i can do it from sd card

Comment: If the application has read permission for that file (it's its own file, or the owner has made it world readable) then yes.  If not, no.  Generally external ("sdcard") is preferred for anything you want to share between unrelated apps.

Comment: By internal Memory i mean the directory that you see when you attacj the tablet to PC. ( not the sandbox )

Comment: You don't see the "internal" memory when you attach a tablet to a pc.  I think you are referring to "built in" "external storage".  Confusing terms, at this point the meaning is really in the permission capabilities of the file system, ("external" lacks them) rather than it being removable.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the directory that i am seeing, i was refrencing it as the internal memory of the tablet, so thats built-in memory of the tablet? so it wont be possible to reach any file pasted by the user in these folders thorught third-party application

Comment: That's an "external storage" though likely a built in one.  Everything there should be accessible to applications and file managers, with the exception of a few encrypted containers that will be accessable but not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks Chris that make some sense. I just want to acces those folder and read some files in the external storage. Can you please provide me link or example that may be help me. I am trying to find but i can't find anything

Comment: Use the api functions to determine the path of the external storage directory on a given install. Then use whatever file handling functions you like.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html

Comment: This is the only one i have found and i think its about SD Card but i cant find anything for the internal storage of the tablet

Comment: You need to stop thinking "internal storage" because that is something else (ie /data).  What you want is the **external** storage or sdcard, even though in this case it's built in rather than removable (just accept that it's confusingly misnamed, on the original devices the memory playing that role was a removable card)

Comment: @Chris: I've lost a lot of time trying to figure out if I lost my mind or there can be built-in "external storage" which file managers (with no permissions except "Storage: modify/delete storage contents") can browse - so thanks for this answer!